# Replace a specific pattern with SED

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I need help on how to write a SED one liner (no awk) that replaces a substring of one line with a pattern in the same length.
For example, if the file looks like:

```
daemon www X=1 ***Y=1,2,2*** Z=
daemon www X=1 ***Y=1,2,2,1,3,4,5*** Z=4
daemon mail a=3
```

I would like to change only lines that contain "daemon www" and the substring Y=.. with same number of  zeros.
(The number of `#,#,#,#` is unknown).

Output file should look like:

```
daemon www X=1 ***Y=0,0,0*** Z=4
daemon www X=1 ***Y=0,0,0,0,0,0,0*** Z=4
daemon mail a=3
```

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: awk admits one-liners too, you know ...

Comment: Why only `sed`? Is this homework? Are those `***` really there?

Comment: @Jaypal: Why would anyone ever need anything *but* sed? SED!

Comment: Sorry. The asterisks suppose to highlight "Y=..." .

Comment: Not homework. Project for work. I'm sure it can be done only with sed...

Comment: @@perreal Thanks ! Perhaps you can update the explanation below so i could understand it better ? Also, Now it stuck in an endless loop if Y=#,#,# is at the end of he line. (if I add a space or another parameter at the end of line it works).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
 sed '/daemon www.*Y=/{:l s/\(Y=\(0,\)*\)[0-9]*/\10/;/Y=\(0,\)*0\([^,0-9]\|$\)/!bl}' input
```

some explanation:

```
if this line contains daemon www and Y=        #  /daemon www.*Y=/{
    loop                                       # :l
      a. find Y= and zeros followed by commas  # s/\(Y=\(0,\)*\)
      b. find a series of digits               # [0-9]*
      c. replace matches in 'a' and 'b' with   # /\10/g
         'a' and 0 
      d. jump to loop if cannot match the 
         desired pattern: Y=0,0..,0            # /Y=\(0,\)*0
      e. and the pattern in d ends with a 
         non-digit non-comma character or the 
         end of line                           # \([^,0-9]\|$\)/!bl
```

Comment: your output looks really strange... Using `GNU sed version 4.2.1`

Comment: still borked. `*` seems to be turned into 0 as well. `daemon www X=1 ***Y=0,0,0,0,0,0,0000 Z=4`

Comment: That's the stuff ! great !!

Comment: Any chance I could get a short explanation ? SED documentation is BAD.

Comment: Looked very complex at start but now it makes sense :) Thanks !!

Comment: @perreal Hi. Any chance we can make it work for number starting with 0 ? for example 05,6 is changed to 00,0 (which is not the same..)

Comment: @perreal Can you please help ?

Comment: @perreal Thanks ! perhaps you could also modify the explanation so I would understand the change ?  Thanks ! Also, if the line ends after Y=#,# without trailing space or another param, it get stuck in an endless loop.

Comment: @perreal now if there's a line starting with "string daemon www" but no Y=... i'm stuck in an endless loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sed '/^daemon www.*Y/{s/[0-9]\([,*]\)/0\1/g}'
```

in action:

```
$ cat input
daemon www X=1 ***Y=1,2,2*** Z=
daemon www X=1 ***Y=1,2,2,1,3,4,5*** Z=4
daemon mail a=3

$ sed '/^daemon www.*Y/{s/[0-9]\([,*]\)/0\1/g}' input
daemon www X=1 ***Y=0,0,0*** Z=
daemon www X=1 ***Y=0,0,0,0,0,0,0*** Z=4
daemon mail a=3
```

Comment: outch, glad someone is paying attention

Comment: +1 though you don't really need to escape inside character class.

Comment: Aah scratch that. You removed it from the `sed in action`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `awk`. But you can disregard it if you really really have to use `sed`.

```
awk '/daemon www.*Y=*/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) ($i~/Y=/)?gsub(/[0-9]/,"0",$i):$i}1' file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
daemon www X=1 ***Y=1,2,2*** Z=
daemon www X=1 ***Y=1,2,2,1,3,4,5*** Z=4
daemon mail a=3 Y=3,45,
$ awk '/daemon www.*Y=*/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) ($i~/Y=/)?gsub(/[0-9]/,"0",$i):$i}1' file
daemon www X=1 ***Y=0,0,0*** Z=
daemon www X=1 ***Y=0,0,0,0,0,0,0*** Z=4
daemon mail a=3 Y=3,45,
```

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{print "Thank You, Fred!"}'` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -e 's/^\(daemon www X=1 .*Y=\)[0-9]\+/\10/' -e 's/,[0-9]\+/,0/g'
```